# Regex add also symbols

Tags: regex

I have regex for password. It's can contain at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters. But I want also add symbols.

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$/
```

Comment: You're very close, just add desired symbols to the set and add a lookahead for symbols if you want to make them required.

Comment: Just add the look ahead for the desired symbols. You should probably only use look aheads and then have `^.{min_len}$` to have a minimum length.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus can you please write. I am not good with regex.

Comment: @karen That's okay, you can practice at https://regex101.com/r/KKt21B/1/. If you get stuck or it's not working how you wish then come back and update your question with your attempt.

Comment: It's working for me, but why regex understanding foreign language as symbol `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d^\S+$]+$`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add another lookahead to contain symbols you want and don't forget to add it to your regex , for example 
if you want to add & or $ then (your regex will be like this):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[&$])[a-zA-Z\d&$]+$
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/f5Komn/2)

Comment: Yes but the symbols can be not required

Comment: then only add it between [] like this `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d&$]+$` and if you want any character except \n then use `.+` instead of  `[a-zA-Z\d&$]+`

Comment: but why regex understanding foreign language as symbol